# How to provide SSL to a no promoted named version in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I have a PHP application on Google App Engine.
Currently, I have a promoted version (production) and it is automatically pointed to my custom domain with SSL certificate.

Then I have another version that has its own .yaml file and I create a version on the same GAE but it is not promoted and also I named it "pre-release" so I can identify from the other versions and it not get overwritten or confuse it with other versions.
The link of this version is: http://pre-release-dot-xxxxx.uc.r.appspot.com/

My question is how can I provide an SSL to this address or can I add this URL to my DNS domain i.e. using a subdomain.

I tried in different ways and still getting HTTP URL and not able to obtain an HTTPS: URL.
Some of the authorization depends on having a SSL and I am not able to use this version for testing.

Comment: are you trying to force https on this version? are you using App Engine Flex or Standard?  By default all the versions are available in Https as well and it can be forced.

Comment: https://pre-release-dot-xxxxx.uc.r.appspot.com/ should work, right out of the box.

Comment: I am using  standard with laravel on the back end (i have used for around 3 years not issues. My promoted version has a SSL certificate and works as intended  using https and my domain not the appspot.com url. When I try to access the url with https  for the non promoted version I got this Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from pre-release.xxx.app.appspot.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: could you please share a sceenshot of the issue? and are you using custom certificates or the Google managed ones?